# what is better *.hpp or *.cpp file to include in *.h file

Tags: c++

I have to run Makefile. which include one of this command `g++ file1.o file2.o file3.h -o output`.

and *My Files* are like :-.

file1.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "file2.h"
#include "file3.h"
using namespace std;
 -----
------
-----
```

and I have file3.h

```
#include<something>
#ifndef X
#define X
-----
function declaration
-----
-----

#include "file3.hpp"
#endif
```

file3.hpp

```
#include "file3.h"
------
-----
function definition
--------
```

Please guide me about this.

can I define function of `file3.h` in `file3.hpp` or should I use `file3.cpp` to define function of `file3.h`.

Comment: Inline functions (including class member functions directly written in class declaration) and template functions should be in headers. Other functions should be in `.cpp`.

Comment: Does the line `g++ file1.o file2.o file3.h -o output` come from a Makefile that *you* wrote, or that someone else did? It's very unusual to feed a header file directly to `g++`, especially in a command that looks like it's aiming to link object files together. Indeed, if that Makefile line did come from someone else, then I'd expect it to have been a typo.

Comment: It's quite odd to have "file3.h" in the g++ command. Why is it there?

Comment: @jjramsey somenoe else did

Comment: file extensions are just a matter of convention. Though, the commonly accepted way of doing stuff means that you should never include `.cpp` files (more generally: source files)

Comment: @molbdnilo someone else gave me Makefile to complete some task.

Comment: *somenoe else did*  It appears to me that the *someone else* doesn't know what they are doing.

Comment: @Rafiuzzaman Then you should ask "someone else" about what they expect you to do. Nobody around here has any idea about what "some task" could be, or what the purpose of that makefile is.

Comment: Hopefully this is just by way of an example, but an include guard like `#define X` is so laconic it could clash with variable names in your program! (X is a fairly standard symbol for a random variable in mathematics).

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, I used X just for  demonstration purpose